# Conditional CSS: if a selector contains another selector?

Tags: html, css

On a page, I have two paragraphs, both of which are identified via `.entry p` selector. However, the first one also includes a timestamp, which is marked with `.time` selector – the code looks like this:

```
<div class="entry">

    <p><span class="time">17:25:22</span> Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus.</p>

    <p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit?</p>

</div>
```

Now, is it possible apply different rules to those two paragraphs without introducing new selectors? Like, because of the condition that the first one contains this `span class="time"`, and the second one does not?

Answer (score 1):

You could use :first-child, in the entry div if the first p is always going to contain a time, then you could just target the first p in the div.

For example:

```
.entry p:first-child {
 css here
}
```

or using Jquery:

```
$('.entry p .time').parent().addClass('p-class');
```

Comment: *"because of the condition that the first one contains this span class="time", and the second one does not?"* - OP was quite specific about the case they're looking for, and I don't think selecting `<p>` by index satisfies that. The hypothetical selector they'd be looking for would target any `<p>` that has a `.time` child. It's not possible.

Comment: @Santi OP is trying to target the paragraph that contains time. If it's always going to be the first paragraph in the entry div, then :first-child would be a good option.

Comment: Unfortunately, there will be more those timestamps down the page. It's just they are mixed with no-timestamps paragraphs.

Comment: Then I'd use jquery to target all `$('.entry p  .time').parent().addClass('special-p');` or whatever the class would be.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, @PaigeMeinke.

Comment: @As jQuery also has a [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/): `$("p:has(.time)").addClass("myClass");`